# How to send Participant-Specific information via CiviMail

Tags: civievent, civimail, custom-fields, tokens

We are running a hybrid event where some participants are virtual via Zoom and some participants attend in person. We need to send out reminders and the zoom link to virtual attendees, and also want to send reminders to "in person" attendees along with the link so that if they change their minds, they can attend virtually.

So we want to send different messages to the two kind of attendees, and in addition, we would like to include other participant-specific information, such as the number of raffle tickets purchased, etc.

I know that I can do an advanced search for virtual attendees of the specific event, and send a civimail message to that group, then do another advanced search for in person attendees of the same event, and then send a different civimail message to that group. But if I wanted to extend to telling them the number of raffle tickets they have purchased, I would be dealing with more and more searches and unique mail messages to each of many groups.

Is it possible to include participant specific info in a CiviMail message? Sort of a mail-merge capability as with current contact-specific tokens, but extended to participant-specific tokens.

Thanks in advance for any pointers!
Rick

Comment: have a look at the fuzion tokens extension - it may give you what you need https://civicrm.org/extensions/fuzion-tokens

Comment: Thanks Pete! That didn't give us the tokens for an event that we are looking for but it does have a number of tokens re: memberships and relationships that will be very handy. We'll install it!

Comment: always happy to accept more tokens if you want to provide a PR

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that - when we get our membership up we will revisit!

Answer (score 2):

There is a rather new extension called "Custom Event Communivation" that allows you to sent emails to participants both automated (e.g. on registration / status change) or based on a participant search. Have a look at the documentation: https://docs.civicrm.org/eventmessages/en/latest/

Also have a look at the event invitation Extension in case you want to invite participants to an event: https://docs.civicrm.org/eventinvitation/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

OK, so this is a partial answer to my question - don't use CiviMail but use Scheduled Reminders instead - a reminder about a specific event will have access to tokens such as event summary, event start date, etc. so I can send a reminder to those signed up for an event and use tokens to specify the event. The reminder can be reused for other events without changing the body.

That's the gist, here's more detail

So there aren't tokens specific to events available from CiviMail (except that the Fuzion Tokens Extension has lots of things that are close - such as a list of upcoming events, etc., and it adds tons of tokens about latest membership start, end, fee level, etc. THANK YOU EILEEN, and @petednz for pointing me there)
However Scheduled Reminders DOES have information about events. It doesn't necessarily have tokens for some custom fields that we use during registration, but it does have lots of information as detailed below. So whereas I can't seem to get a list of attendees for an event and then email their particular registration, I CAN cause an email to automatically be sent to attendees of a particular event via scheduled reminders.

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/email/scheduled-reminders/#tokens-available-to-scheduled-reminders
*Tokens available to scheduled reminders¶
In addition to the standard tokens that are available in CiviMail, messages sent via scheduled reminders can also contain tokens representing information about events, activities, contributions and memberships that the scheduled reminder pertains to. This allows you to use one scheduled reminder template for various events, membership, contribution or activity types.
In event messages, tokens such as event location will be replaced with the specific location of the event. In membership messages, you have access to each individuals expiry date, and so on. Membership and event ID tokens are also available and can be used to create links to specific pages (such as the membership renewal page).
Note that you also have access to the checksum token which allows you to authenticate people to specific pages without them needing to log in, and show forms with details already filled in.*